# Best way to use retrofit response in several activies

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

I have a function *searchForTrips()* which sends an API request and fetch some response in following way.

```
private void searchForTrips(){

    int departurePortId = PORT_ID_LIST.get(departurePort);
    int returnPortId = PORT_ID_LIST.get(returnPort);
    int pax= Integer.parseInt(noOfPassengers);
    String departureDatePARSED = DEPARTURE_DATE_VALUES.get(departureDate);
    String returnDatePARSED = RETURN_DATE_VALUES.get(departureDate);

    Call<TripSearchResponse> call = apiService.searchAvailableTrips(TripType,departurePortId,returnPortId,departureDatePARSED,returnDatePARSED,pax);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<TripSearchResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<TripSearchResponse> call, Response<TripSearchResponse> response) {
            int statusCode = response.code();
            switch(statusCode){
                case 200:

                default:
                    Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),"Error loading data. Network Error.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<TripSearchResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.i(TAG, t.getMessage());
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),"Error loading data. Network Error.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}
```

The purpose is to make this callback function reusable so I can call it from several activities and get requested data as I need. What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: you can create static method somewhere which will handle your response

Comment: There are multiple ways, 1. Singleton, 2. MVP, 3 Interfaces etc, but you have to choose which one is convenient. if i have to call multiple times for same services i'll start with interfaces

Comment: you can use dagger2 singleton.

Comment: @ErginErsoy Ok, can  you help me with a good example of it?

Comment: do you know how to use dagger2 ?

Comment: @ErginErsoy Sorry, no. But I am eager to learn it, if its any good.

Comment: it is a plus for Android applications. I suggest you to learn. Any example at this moment will be pointless. Because you will be confused

Comment: @ErginErsoy Thanks a lot. I will definitely look into it.

Answer (score 0):

try this way, its dynamic way and easy to use:

Create Retforit Interface:

```
public interface ApiEndpointInterface {

    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST(Constants.SERVICE_SEARCH_TRIP)
    Call<JsonObject> searchForTrip(@Body TripRequest objTripRequest);

}
```

Create Retrofit Class:

```
public class AppEndPoint {

    private static Retrofit objRetrofit;

    public static ApiEndpointInterface getClient() {
        if (objRetrofit == null){
            objRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(Constants.SERVER_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return objRetrofit.create(ApiEndpointInterface.class);
    }
}
```

Create this helper Classes/Interfaces to hold web service callback:

```
public enum ResponseState {
    SUCCESS,
    FAILURE,
    NO_CONNECTION
}

public enum RequestType {
    SEARCH_FOR_TRIP // add name for each web service
}


public class Response {
    public ResponseState state;
    public boolean hasError;
    public RequestType requestType;
    public JsonObject result;
}

public interface RestRequestInterface {
    void Response(Response response);
    Context getContext();
}

public class ResponseHolder { used to hold the Json response could be changed as your response

    @SerializedName("is_successful")
    @Expose
    private boolean isSuccessful;

    @SerializedName("error_message")
    @Expose
    private String errorMessage;


    public boolean isSuccessful() {
        return isSuccessful;
    }

    public void setSuccessful(boolean successful) {
        isSuccessful = successful;
    }

    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return errorMessage;
    }

    public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }
}

public class AppClient {
    private static ApiEndpointInterface objApiEndpointInterface;
    private static Response objResponse;
    private static Call<JsonObject> objCall;


    // implement new method like below for each new web service
    public static void searchForTrip(TripRequest objTripRequest, RestRequestInterface objRestRequestInterface) {
        objResponse = new Response();
        objResponse.state = ResponseState.FAILURE;
        objResponse.hasError = true;
        objResponse.requestType = RequestType.SEARCH_FOR_TRIP; // set type of the service from helper interface

        objApiEndpointInterface = AppEndPoint.getClient();
        objCall = objApiEndpointInterface.searchForTrip(objTripRequest);
        handleCallBack(objRestRequestInterface);
    }

    private static void handleCallBack(final RestRequestInterface objRestRequestInterface) {
        objCall.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, retrofit2.Response<JsonObject> response) {
                try {
                    ResponseHolder objResponseHolder = new Gson().fromJson(response.body(), ResponseHolder.class);
                    if (objResponseHolder.isSuccessful()) {
                        objResponse.state = ResponseState.SUCCESS;
                        objResponse.hasError = false;
                        objResponse.result = response.body();
                    } else {
                        objResponse.errorMessage = objResponseHolder.getErrorMessage();
                    }
                    objRestRequestInterface.Response(objResponse);

                } catch (Exception objException) {
                    objResponse.errorMessage = objRestRequestInterface.getContext().getString(R.string.server_error);
                    objRestRequestInterface.Response(objResponse);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable objThrowable) {
                String errorMessage = "";
                if (objThrowable instanceof IOException) {
                    errorMessage = objRestRequestInterface.getContext().getString(R.string.no_connection_error);
                } else {
                    errorMessage = objRestRequestInterface.getContext().getString(R.string.server_error);
                }
                objResponse.errorMessage = errorMessage;
                objRestRequestInterface.Response(objResponse);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

then go to your activity of fragment and make the call like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RestRequestInterface {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // initialize ids

        // prepare to call web service

        // 1.Initialize your object to be sent over web service
        TripRequest objTripRequest = new TripRequest();
        objTripRequest.id = 1;

        // 2.Show loader

        // 3.Make the call
        AppClient.searchForTrip(objTripRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void Response(Response response) {
        // hide loader
        try {
            if (response.state == ResponseState.SUCCESS && !response.hasError) {
                // check the type of web service
                if (response.requestType == RequestType.SEARCH_FOR_TRIP) {
                    // acces the return here from  response.result
                }
            } else {
                String errorMsg = response.hasError ? response.errorMessage : getString(R.string.no_connection_error);
                // show the error to the user
            }
        } catch (Exception objException) {
            // show the error to the user
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Context getContext() {
        // do not forgit set the context here
        // if fragment replace with getAcitvity();
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. I will definitely try it out. Thanks a lot.